# Adding a new Line with writter class

Tags: java

I have the following code That I am trying to write different lines in a text file but when I add line break \n it doe not perform what I want Instead all lines are on the same line. How can I correct it? The section of code is this

```
Writer writer = null;
File file = new File("C:/output.txt");
writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
//code to iterate 
writer.write(output);
writer.write("\n");
// code to close each line
```

Answer (score 5):

On Windows, the default line break (used by notepad etc) is `"\r\n"`. You can use the platform-default line break by calling [`BufferedWriter.newLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine%28%29):

```
// This would replace your call to writer.write("\n")
writer.newLine();
```

Of course, your file may then look odd on non-Windows boxes... basically text files aren't as portable as you might expect. If you want to make sure it writes the Windows line break even if you're *running* on (say) a Linux box, you'd write `writer.write("\r\n")` instead.

Along those lines, you should at least consider using `OutputStreamWriter` wrapping a `FileOutputStream` instead of `FileWriter` - that way you can specify the encoding to use, e.g. UTF-8. Currently your code will use the platform default encoding, which may not be what you really want.

Answer (score 2):

Try using System.getProperty("line.separator")...

Comment: Perhaps you meant `System.getProperty("line.separator")`?

Answer (score 2):

do you tried

`writer.newLine();`

The [documentation of the JDK](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html) says:

A newLine() method is provided, which uses the platform's own notion of line separator as defined by the system property line.separator. Not all platforms use the newline character ('\n') to terminate lines.

So it should work with the underlying OS.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. Just i realized that my code worked well with '\n' but th e problem was to write in txt file and then open it using notepad. Notepad ignore \n but wordpad does not.